# Oracle 11g Express Configuration For Archive mode

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm new in oracle database, I have installed oracle 11g express in one machine as server and installed another machine with same steps for stand by database, but when i have take backup of server database and restore database on standby database getting error `like...

> ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get error below
>    ORA-01122: database file 9 failed verification check 
>    ORA-01110: data file 9: 'H:\xxx\xxx\system.dbf'
>    ORA-01206: file is not part of this database - wrong database id

I have also checked SID, both have same instance but have different sid.

`Like server have SID = 13 and Stand by have SID=91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid this error add the following entries in pfile(clone/duplicate database)

```
db_file_name_convert='+DATA/DEMODB/DATAFILE/','/u01/app/oracle/oradata/dupdb/'
log_file_name_convert='+DATA/DEMODB/ONLINELOG/','/u01/app/oracle/oradata/dupdb/'
```

or set new name command in rman script.

11G R1 and below

```
    SET NEWNAME FOR DATAFILE 1 TO ‘/dup/oracle/oradata/trgt/system01.dbf’;
    SET NEWNAME FOR DATAFILE 2 TO ‘/dup/oracle/oradata/trgt/undotbs01.dbf’;
    and so on for all files , you can write a dynamic script to generate the output , something like 
        select 'set newname for datafile ' || file_id to 'path/' || file_name ||    ';' from dba_data_files;
```

11G R2 and onwards

```
        SET NEWNAME FOR DATABASE   TO 'D:\oracle\oradata\orcl\%b';
        SET NEWNAME FOR TEMPFILE 1 TO 'D:\oracle\oradata\orcl\temp01.dbf' ;
```

Edit 2 : Backups

To backup only  archivelog

```
backup archivelog all;
```

To backup db along with archive log

```
BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
```

If you want to restore them to dg then simply copy over (scp) to the dg server and catalog and start recovery, but if the gap is too big then you have to a 
"Roll Forward" recovery, which is nothing but an incremental backup and restore and recovery of dg.

Follow this link for that "http://thegeekdiary.com/how-to-roll-forward-a-standby-database-using-rman-incremental-backup-in-11g/"

Comment: @Singhisking see the example provided

Comment: Problem is that how can i change sid? at one side either Server (physical Database) or stand by physical database.

Comment: I have same db structure even file name are same both side then why we need to change file names ?

Comment: go through this link if you're setting up the dg for the first time  "http://allthingsoracle.com/data-guard-physical-standby-database-best-practices-part-i/ "

Comment: i'm not use any data guard, just simple i have do install oracle express and enable archive mode same as installed on another machine for stand by database and enable archive mode and take back up of primary database and execute restore script for restore database after restore done getting below error `like "file is not part of this database - wrong database id".

Comment: please explain how can configure oracle database to take archive back up and restore on stand by database?

Comment: i have use this query for check sid " select distinct sid from v$mystat;".

Comment: what are you checking sid for ? what do you actually want to do ? be specific

Comment: I have two machine in lan network , In one machine i have installed **oracle 11g express** and use second machine for **stand by** purpose so i have installed same oracle 11g express on another machine & Enable archive mode in both machine with execute same script.Now i have take **backup with archive** from first machine and just **restore in another machine for stand by purpose**.But getting error during restore database like _""file is not part of this database - wrong database id"_

Comment: Just use as a create database replica (**for mirroring purpose**) through manual effort.

Comment: that is not how a standby database works, the database you installed in other machine is a different database and it will have a different db ID , thats the reason you are getting the error. , you need to restore your existing primary database as a standby database. You're controlfile should be backed up as ' for standby database' and restore an empty instance with the db_name as primary db name and db_unique_name as standby db name and restore. I have already provided you a link on how to create a standby database step by step.    Have you followed it ?

Comment: Thanks for help, please suggest me how can i do it step by step process for create stand by database.

Comment: ive already commented on how to create step by step .                                            Use this link and learn
http://allthingsoracle.com/data-guard-physical-standby-database-best-practices-part-i/

Comment: Yes, but above link for setup standby database through **Data Guard**. I don't go with **Data Guard** want some manual activity for setup Standby Database. I have execute batch script and take backup on scheduled time and restore on stand by database after every 15 min.

Comment: that is completely strange , why would you want to do somethiing manually when oracle will do it for you ? If you still want to do that, then like I said earlier, take backup and restore and do roll forward restore using archive logs. I've shared the link also in previous comments.

Comment: i have done same configuration in oracle standard edition and this working perfectly without **Data Guard** due to some software licensing problem, i don't want to go with Data Guard.